# iOS stringWithFormat shorthand WITH nil check

Tags: nsstring, shorthand, stringwithformat

I am trying to make a shorthand for `[NSString stringWithFormat]`:

How can I turn this (working):

```
  #define fstring(s, ...) [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__]
```

into this (with a check for nil value)

```
  #define fstring(s, ...) [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__ (__VA_ARGS__ ?:@"")]
```

Something like:

```
NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", contact.firstName ?: @""]
```

I have tried different shorthand combinations without luck... anybody got a better idea?

**EDIT - Solution found**

```
#define fstring(s, ...) [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__ ?:@""]
```

Comment: out of curiosity, why? Seems like it would just add another layer of indirection that makes your code harder to read for someone who knows Objective-C and the Foundation classes.

Comment: Well, good point... basically to make long code shorter, without compromising readability... i cant imagine it is hard to read something like fstring(@"%@", boo)?

Comment: Writing "native" code is better for XCode auto-complete and color-coding, and mixing metaphors *is* less readable, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks :) I appreciate, but I don't think it will make much of a difference in this case. I would rather write less when it is obvious like this :)

Comment: I realize this doesn't answer the question, but perhaps for the sake of maintaining the "native" quality of the code you should consider creating an xcode Code Snippet shortcut for this: http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/

I created one I use regularly that auto-fills the full syntax when I simply type "nss" because I, like you, got REALLY tired of typing out (and often mis-capitalizing) NSString stringWithFormat.... blah, blah.

Comment: Thanks very much for the update :) I will consider using snippets more often. In the meantime, i started using Swift, and this exact problem is much easier using swift print("The result is \(result)")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is the following:

```
#define fstring(s, ...) [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__ ?:@""]
```

and if you want with empty string if null:

```
#define fstringOrEmpty(...) __VA_ARGS__ ? : @""
```